# What are the differences between the variations of JEXL?

Tags: java, jexl

Does anyone know the best place where I can go to see the differences between the variations of JEXL? I've noted the following so far.

**Expression**

This only allows for a single command to be executed and the result from that is returned. If you try to use multiple commands it ignores everything after the first semi-colon and just returns the result from the first command.

**Script**

This allows you to put multiple commands in the expression and you can use variable assignments, loops, calculations, etc. The result from the last command is returned from the script.

**Unified**

This is ideal for text. To get a calculation you use the EL-like syntax as in ${someVariable}. The expression that goes between the brackets behaves like a script, not an expression. You can use semi-colons to execute multiple commands and the result from the last command is returned from the script.

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://commons.apache.org/jexl/?

Comment: Thanks, Zecas. The current maintainer confirmed the above summary and added it to the JEXL javadoc. http://www.mail-archive.com/user@commons.apache.org/msg06685.html